# Tabs with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on this page: https://www.landingpagedude.ca/max-ahg/
I have 3 tabs (Product demonstration, Expert chat sessions and Virtual Reality at its best!) as you can see in the image: https://prnt.sc/mmvin2

I would like that when clicking on any of the tabs, change the content that is below the tab, referring to the clicked tab.

This content https://prnt.sc/mmvjsn is referring to the first tab:

The other 2 may be any random content. The only detail is that the selected tab must be active, with the same style when hovering over the tab (hover)

This is the mobile view: https://prnt.sc/mmvmi1

Makes sense? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect which tab was clicked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059648/detect-which-tab-was-clicked-with-jquery)

Comment: Please add relevant code here as a [mcve], as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: There are lots of ready made tabs plugins you could use. A short Google search would find good results. What have you tried so far? What problem are you facing? We are here to help you, but we're not a free provider of research effort or full code solutions. You haven't actually asked us a question or described any kind of difficulty that you would like us to assist with.

Answer (score 1):

This was taken from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) i just edited to what you are trying accomplish. I Recommend u do some research in this topic to see what will suit u best, because there are frameworks like [Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) that might help.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on images and the contect will apper at the Buttom of it</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')"><img width="50mm" src="https://images.discordapp.net/avatars/485508882475778058/c03979b0f78a5a5ec2badca1f1520f14.png?size=512"></button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')"><img width="100mm" src="https://singularityhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/man-into-virtual-reality-world_shutterstock_519713428-1068x601.jpg"></button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')"><img width="100mm" src="http://www.chutingstar.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/e/aerodyne_pilot_1.jpg"></button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  Choose from NSW, VIC or QLD product demonstrations and let us take you on the ultimate product journey.
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```